# Object Mapping in RestKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, restkit

I have a JSON response of this format

```
{"status":
{
"id":0,
"offerList":[{"offerId":38,"title":"TITLE OFFER 38","shortDescription":"OFFER PCT 38","orginalPrice":100,"image":"offer-38.jpg","description":"DESCRIPTION OFFER 38","shopId":4,"startDate":"5/29/2011 12:00:00 AM","endDate":"8/10/2011 12:00:00 AM","startTime":"16:30:00","endTime":"21:59:59","insertionDate":"7/5/2011 4:42:40 AM","categoryId":0,"subCategoryId":0,"published":1}

"shopList":[{"id":4,"name":"Store 1","street":"Street Store 1","postCode":"88214","city":"Barcelona","state":"","country":"Spain, Kingdom of","description":"Loc Description Store 1","url":"http://www.store-1.com","email":"store1@gmail.com","telephone":"Phone-number-store-1","published":1,"lastUpdated":"7/5/2011 4:42:40 AM","latitude":41.4398,"longitude":2.1601}]
}
}
```

I am using restkit for object mapping. What could be the possible way to map this JSON using RKManaged Object.
Could  someone help please. I am stuck for past 3 days.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zach, you should probably ask this question on the [RestKit](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/restkit) mailing list and be a bit more specific as to what you want to achieve.

Regardless, RestKit author Blake Watters just posted a [new document describing Object Mapping](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping), which should answer all your questions. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, this link seems to be not working. Could you please update. Thanks

Comment: I've updated the link - the RestKit project has recently moved there github repository, hence non-working link

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot. I am wondering why I am not able to create a RKObjectMapping object. Instead I am getting RKOBjectMapper. Do I need to import some other classes

Comment: The new tutorial by Blake Watters is quite good. Thank you so much Blake!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is to no help, but I had a problem where RestKit crashed when trying to map my objects and the problem was that I tried to map a value to keypath 'description'. This was not doable though because 'description' is a keyword in Objective-C. Try change that name to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Zach,

Whatever is the name of the corresponding mapping in JSON, you refer to as **keyPath**.
Using RestKit 0.9.2, with new Object Mapping:

I'll assume that you need one-to-many relationship from Status (parent) to Offers and Shops (children), and the property names are kinda implicit here.

Usually in your app delegate, you can configure your mappings then like this:

```
RKObjectMapping* statusMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Status class]];
[statusMapping mapKeyPathToAttributes:@"statusId",@"id"] // This maps JSON status.id to objc Status.statusId

RKObjectMapping* offerMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Offer class]];
// Add more pairs as needed in the line below
[offerMapping mapKeyPathToAttributes:@"offerId",@"offerId",@"title",@"title",@"shortDescription",@"shortDescription"];

//Do the same thing for your Shop mapping

//Configure relationships:
//Assumes Status class has a property of type NSArray* offers that will contain multiple orders
[statusMapping mapKeyPath:@"orderList" toRelationship:@"orders" withObjectMapping:offerMapping];

//Do the same thing for your Shop relationship
```

Regards,

Comment: Hi I cant find RKObjectMapping instead I am getting RKObjectMapper! Do i need to import any additional headers?

Comment: What version of RestKit are you using? I'm sure that if you have the 0.9.2 tagged version, it has RKObjectMapping if you include <RestKit/Restkit.h>